# How to maintain the page folder structure in pelican?

Tags: python-2.7, markdown, pelican

I've copied several folders inside the path content/pages. After running the pelican content command, I get the html files converted under the output folder where all the html files are copied under output/pages as a whole.

For ex:

If I have the folder structure:

content

```
    - pages

           - hello
                  - hello.html

           - world
                  - world.html
```

I get the output as:

output

```
     - pages

            - hello.html
            - world.html
```

I need to retain the original folder structure in the output folder.

The USE_FOLDER_AS_CATEGORY = True option didn't work. Apparently, it works only for Articles not for pages.

Is there any other way to build the folder structure?

Comment: Hi Sri. Did the answer I provided solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Justin. Rather using that , I used a simple method in the peliconconf.py :  



     `PATH_METADATA= '(?P<path_no_ext>.*)\..*'
     PAGE_SAVE_AS='{path_no_ext}.html' `


This works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following plugin was designed for the exact use case you described: https://github.com/akhayyat/pelican-page-hierarchy